# AWS Crawler stuck in STOPPING state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, schemacrawler

I have a crawler that was working fine defining the schema of a parquet file in S3, but I came across a CrawlerRunningException when I ran it again.
I checked its status and it has been stuck in STOPPING for some reason I don´t get.
I can´t even delete the crawler to recreate it, at least from the Aws Console.

Does anybody knows why this happens and how to procede?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nico, do you achieved to solve it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry I can´t remember how this problem was solved. 
Cant´remember if I just waited until the crawler was ready again, since it had to crawl a large dataset in S3. Or with redeploying your resources again with Cloud Formation fixed this issue.

Comment: No problem, I did some requests to start/stop crawler using aws sdk and after some minutes my crawler return to 'ready' state.